# Spell check in QML text input components for Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, qt, qml, spell-checking

Can standard spell-checking be enabled in QML text input components on Android and iOS?

```
TextInput {} 
TextArea {}
TextField {}
```

In Android, spell-checking is enabled/disabled in the phone settings and works for all apps. For iOS, it is similar but with more settings. I want to use the built-in spell-check mechanism.

[image]